# Close Mic beep Sound or Sound of single Application Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can we Close All sounds of single application that will not effect other apps sound or general sound , or

i am working on voice recognition app , is there any solution to close mic beep sound , because i have to take repeatedly input from user and beep sound of mic start and stop is distrubing
Thanks in advance

Comment: did yu resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val amanager: AudioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    amanager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
}
```

In MainActivity.kt, this should mute most things.